# insert into using default value on database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've facing problem insert value using Excel Import.

And there is my App\Imports

```
     <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Pelanggan;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class PelangganImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Pelanggan([
            'id_pelanggan'                      => $row[0],
            'nama_pelanggan'                    => $row[1],
            'alamat1_pelanggan'                 => $row[2],
            'alamat2_pelanggan'                 => $row[3],
            'id_kategori_pelanggan'             => $row[4],
            'id_channel'                        => $row[5],
            'id_outlet'                         => $row[6],
            
        ]);



        if ($row [7]){
            $dataArray['id_subdist'] = $row[7];

        }
    }
}
```

On Migrate table I was set default to "DUMMY"

```
$table->string('id_subdist',30)->default('DUMMY')->comment('id_subdist/dso');
```

I'm using laravel 8.6 and My database is MySql

Comment: why you are passing $row[7] ->default('DUMMY')? I think it should be $row[7]

Comment: because, when data import using excel and `NULL` it be set to `default` sometime data will be update next time and sometime have value

Comment: `$row[7] ?? 'Dummy'` ?

Comment: @lagbox , yes for default value when column is `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the database table column default value then it will enter the default value if you are specifying any value at the time when you are entering a new row to the table.

When importing you can have a check and if `id_subdist` is available then add to the database, if not let database handle it and add the default value automatically.

```
$dataArray = [
   'id_pelanggan'                      => $row[0],
   'nama_pelanggan'                    => $row[1],
   'alamat1_pelanggan'                 => $row[2],
   'alamat2_pelanggan'                 => $row[3],
   'id_kategori_pelanggan'             => $row[4],
   'id_channel'                        => $row[5],
   'id_outlet'                         => $row[6]
];

if ($row[7]){
    $dataArray['id_subdist'] = $row[7];
}

return new Pelanggan($dataArray);
```

Database will automatically will enter the default value to `id_subdist` if it is not available.

Comment: If I do that, when using excel to import column `id_subdist` it couldn't. Because only write will be could be `import`

Comment: I updated the code so if you have a value to ``id_subdist`` it will add to database or else it will add the default value.

Comment: I was tried, with your code. But when insert with have value, it will be to default value `DUMMY`

Comment: What are the values you have in ``id_subdist``?

Comment: I'm using value `TEST` for row 1 and 2. and other row is `NULL`

Comment: You can try ``if (trim($row[7]) != NULL){``.

Comment: I was tried, and result is same, all value on column `id_subdist` will be `DUMMY`

Comment: The code is correct. I think you should check what is the actual value contains in ``$row[7]`` in runtime. It might be coming up null all the time.

Comment: I thought problem because is missing `'id_subdist'=> $row[7] ` but if I add that code will must have value on colum `id_subdist`. I was re-check on actual value is no problem

Comment: Oh... Is my bad.
I'm apologize because I wasn't copy your all code.
When I copy your code is working.

Comment: can you help explain to me about why use `$dataArray` for first time not use `return new Pelanggan([`

Comment: I used ``$dataArray`` because then I can customize the array as I want. When you do ``return new Pelanggan([]);`` the return array is fixed.